# Getting errors while using @setup scenario(called an api, captured specific info from response) and sending it into another scenario outline

Tags: api, automation, automated-tests, karate, web-api-testing

I tried using @setup but it is getting failed. For example, in one feature file I have wrote a secenario and tagged with @setup, here I have called an api and captured the Ids more or less 100 ids. These Ids I am passing it as another scenario api call in the path

```
@setup
Scenario:
   * url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
    * path id
    * method get
    * def testIds = $[*].Id # captured 100 Ids from the this call 

Scenario Outline:
    * url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
    * path id
    * method get

Examples:
      | karate.setup().testIds |
```

Still I am stumble to fix the issue when calling an API capture the Ids dynamically and passing them into another api request. Please refer the following details. Could you please let me know how to fix the issue?

When I am trying to run the entire feature file getting following error for @setup scenario(where we are calling anothe api and capture Id's into jsonObject . But, it is not displaying while run the scenario by scenarios

`01:14:41.185 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, http call failed after 604 milliseconds for url:`

Where I am going to consume the above call response information in this scenario outline, got the following error

`ERROR dynamic expression evaluation failed:`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. Refer to the docs to understand this:

```
Feature: HTTP calls in a loop

@setup
Scenario:
* url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
* method get

Scenario Outline: id: ${id} | name: ${name}
* url `https://httpbin.org/anything/${id}`
* param name = name
* method get

Examples:
| karate.setup().response |
```

Comment: Well it may be working but, not working for me and mess up with following errors while running feature file. But it is not happening when I run file individually instead of using the @setup tag and using it in other scenario examples. Please refer the following:  ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, http call failed after 580 milliseconds for url:

Comment: @PSP you may have an issue in your environment (e.g. HTTP proxy) that only you or some IT support in your co can figure out. if you really need someone to help you - you HAVE to provide a way to replicate - so follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: thanks for reply and also I am sorry could not reply due to personal obligations. Definitely, will proceed further based your provided solutions.