# For Karate, how can I use Scenario Outline set a value in request json file from other csv file

Tags: json, csv, karate

Here is my code:

```
Scenario Outline: test1
* def requestSamp = read('API.json')
* set requestSamp.Test1 = #(Test1)
Examples:
| read('test1.csv')|
```

API.json is:

{
"Test1": "217751",
"Test2": "IL",
"Test3": "1"
}

My test1.csv turn into json:

{
"Test1": "1",
"Test2": "2",
"Test3": "3",
"Result": "Y"
},
{
"Test1": "4",
"Test2": "5",
"Test3": "6",
"Result": "Y"
},
{
"Test1": "7",
"Test2": "8",
"Test3": "9",
"Result": "N"
}

But what I get is

```
{
"Test1": "#(Test1)",
"Test2": "IL",
"Test3": "1"
}
```

Am I able to set an value form one json to another json with Scenario Outline with three different cases?
Just like

```
{
"Test1": "1",
"Test2": "IL",
"Test3": "1"
}
```

```
{
"Test1": "4",
"Test2": "IL",
"Test3": "1"
}
```

```
{
"Test1": "7",
"Test2": "IL",
"Test3": "1"
}
```

Comment: sorry I can't understand your question. maybe you should use the `@setup` style, refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76785467/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/75991456/143475

Comment: Sry for the unclear question, I want to ask if there are any method or expression that can change the Test1 data in my json file?
If i use 
* set requestSamp.Test1 = #(Test1)
it will show "Test1": "#(Test1)",
If i use * set requestSamp.Test1 = [#(Test1)]
it will show "Test1": ["1"],

But I want is without a []

Comment: your use of set and embedded expressions is wrong: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions - there is more, but I can't go into details. why don't you explain what you are trying to do, and most likely there is a better way. did you even read the example links above ? also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052748/143475